# Connector/Python Select statement not working

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

Could someone please help me figure out what's wrong with the following code. It's a Python application that's trying to select from a mysql database using [Connector/Python](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html)

```
number = '+12345678901'
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM channel WHERE phone_number = %s', (number))
```

It's producing the following error:

> 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1

When I check the mysql log, I see the following:

> SELECT * FROM channel WHERE phone_number = %s

This means it's not substituting the phone number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Python Database API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) parameters should *be provided as sequence or mapping* and `(number)` is neither one.

To create a single element tuple you need a comma after the element.

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM channel WHERE phone_number = %s', (number, ))
```

Comment: BTW, I guess you can also replace the string using python as well. For eg, `'SELECT * FROM channel WHERE phone_number = %s' % (number)`

Comment: @mohit that's susceptible to sql injection attack. Sql queries strings should not be concatenated in such manner.

Answer (score -2):

The str.format() method is now used inplace of %s

```
    number = '+12345678901'
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM channel WHERE phone_number = {}').format(number))
```

Happened at about python2.6-ish, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=string.format#format-string-syntax

Comment: This is conflating mysql driver statement interpolation with python interpolation. If you're interpolating queries this way (python rather than SQL) you open yourself to SQL injection attacks.